# Is our quantity of memory infinity?

Tags: information

If our quantity of memory is infinity, how can store in our memory non recursive theories with infinite axioms like true arithmetic, i.e, 1st order Peano Arithmetic + all the natural numbers are standard?
The questio was blocked because something argues wrongly that it doesn´t fit with the accepted themes in the forum. That´s not true. My question is about "Mathematics in the context of physics
Example: What is the relation between renormalization in physics and divergent series in mathematics?"

Comment: The title says "is", but the body of the question says "if". Nothing (with the possible exception of the universe) is infinite.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it (as currently written) is not about physics.

Comment: The conscienciousness is a physical system. The question is only about physics. If you dislike the question, just no comment. I have no problem no physicist in forums, but persons that doesn´t know what physics is...If i were a moderator, I wouldn´t include in the forum. I can´t vote, sorry, but it would be trivial mi vote for the comment and the commenter. If you are talking about "true arithmetic", well, it is introduced in first year in spanish university in calculus I. I don´t know the syllabus in another countries, but I suspect that it must be the same

Comment: we do not know true arithmetic, we only know it exists. There is an infinite number of axioms that we will never know.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle

Answer (score 2):

The size of a memory device is physically limited. Even if it were unlimited only a limited volume is accessible due to read out time. Anyway, how did you get the idea that memory can even remotely be unlimited?

Comment: Because "true arithmetic" is a non recursive axiomatizable theory, it requires an infinite quantity of memory